# How can I change the height of a element on image load?

Tags: jquery, image, load, height

I wrote a function to change the height of an element on image load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


  $("img").load(function() {
    var width = $(this).width();
    $(".item").height(width*0.85);
  });
```

The problem is, when I reload my page, sometimes it works and sometimes not. Just randomley somthimes the height is changed and sometimes not. How can I make it always work

The html:

```
<div class="row row-10 items-grid">
         <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
             <a class="item">
                  <img src="/get/2" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay">
                      <h2 class="">Dogs</h2>
                  </div>
             </a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <a class="item" >
                 <img src="/get/3" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="uppercase">Cats</h2>
               </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the connection between `img` and `.item` HTML codewise?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to loop all images and then add image `onload` event to each one of them individually and when each image is done loading you can update the height of the element which is closest to the image, not all `.item` elements at once, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      var width = $(this).width();
      $this.closest(".item").height(width * 0.85);
    };
    img.src = $(this).attr('src');
  });
});
```

Comment: Why do you add the attribute src?

Comment: Sorry, the snippet will not work. Just wanted to share the code. Also, adding the src attribute triggers the onload event on the new `img` element that we have created.

Comment: I tested your code on my webpage, but the height of "item" does not change

Comment: can you put a console.log inside `onload` function and see if the `width` is coming correct for all images. Also, your images deosn't seem like static images. are you getting them from api?

Comment: "natural width" is not working, I need the width of the image on the page

Comment: I changed the line to `var width = $this.closest(".item").width();`

Comment: Ah no, unfortunately, not every time I load the page, almost everytime, but not always...

Comment: Try updated code and put a console.log inside onload function and see if the width is coming correct for all images.